# Windows 8 default user

Tags: windows-8

While upgrading our network clients one of the machine was initialized with `Online account` instead of `Local account` by mistake. Is there any way to recover from this? I mean deleting this online account and creating local.

We work always inside a local domain but for homogeneity we wanted to have all the client installed the same way.

Thanks.

Comment: Be more precise, what do you mean by "upgrading our network", what infrastructure do you have? Are all the computer the same?

Comment: Yes, we have a simple domain.local Windows network. By the way this question has nothing to do with network infrastructure but only with Windows 8 setup.

Comment: did I said network infrastructure? No I asked about infrastructure, like AD forest, the os alive on the network and so on. This might be the cause of your problem some incompatibility

Comment: @devdept part of the problem might be that the question doesn't make a whole lot of sense as is very ambiguous.  How were you upgrading your clients, what do you mean by "initialized," and what, specifically do you mean online account versus local?  These are all clarifications that your question could really use if you want it to be clear to someone reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are not deploying Windows 8 across your *entire* domain at this point.

When you say *initialized with online account*, do you mean the account created during setup is linked to a Windows Live ID/Microsoft Account? If that is the case, you should be able to create a new local account (http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/5536-user-account-add-new-user-windows-8-a.html) and then delete the other.

If you are talking more along the lines of auto-login, this should help: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/5536-user-account-add-new-user-windows-8-a.html.

If neither of these options come close to the mark, could you explain further what you mean by "initialized"?

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to delete/create users.

If you sign in to your Microsoft account and you want to switch to a local account in Windows 8 do the following:

1. Open the Charms Bar, and click on the Settings charm, then select
   More PC settings.
2. Click Users and then select Switch to a local account.
3. Enter the password of your Microsoft account, and click Next.
4. Type in a user name, password, and password hint that you want
   for your local user account, and click on Next.
5. Click on Sign out and finish.
6. Sign in to your new local user account

This will preserve all of your account data, settings, documents, etc.